# JPA Repository select without relationship entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have two entities (hibernate) with relationship. When I get entity by JPA Reposiotory then hibernate do 'select' for two entity. How I can get entity by one select (in this moment i don't need second entity).

Sorry for my English and technical language - i'm beginner.

Edit

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Medicament> medicaments;

//and others and getters and setters
}
```

Medicament:

```
@Entity
public class Medicament {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

//and others and getters and setters
}
```

I call method from autowired interface UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

@Query("select u from User u where name = :name")
User findByNameQuery(@Param("name") String name);

User findByName(String name);
}
```

Both method `findByNameQuery` and `findByName` do multiple select

Comment: If you are using Criteria api you can use `setFetchMode(FetchMode.LAZY)`, also you can specify `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` in your relatonship annotation

Comment: post the code of those entities

Comment: I added entities; @Pragnani Kinnera how I can use setFetchMode in my code?

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera `Criteria api you can use setFetchMode(FetchMode.LAZY)`. I don't think this will not work. It works the other way round. We can define a relationship as LAZY in the entity mapping and using Criteria we can make it fetch eagerly using `FetchMode.EAGER`. But once we specify it as EAGER in the entity mapping itself, it cannot be changed using Criteria or HQL to load it LAZY. You may want to try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Medicament> medicaments;
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Medicament> medicaments;
```

Or do not specify the FetchType at all. The default for `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` is `LAZY` and `EAGER` for `@OneToOne`

Comment: Glad you got it working. Please, use comments when you want to react to one's answer. Definitely use the second snippet, you can use the getter to get the related entities - that is the charm of JPA :) It doesn't matter whether you use `LAZY` or `EAGER`. The only difference is when the 'second' query is run. When you use `EAGER`, all related entites are looked up immediately. If you use `LAZY` loading, related entites are looked up when you access the attribute/getter. Mark this answer as accepted if it was helpful for you please :)

Comment: What about `@ManyToOne` ? Is also `Fetch.EAGER` as default?

Answer (score 0):

@Tomas Kralik it's working! Thanks!

Can you tell me what is better to use?

Entity with LAZY fetch and use this in controller:

```
User user = userRepository.findByName(name);
List<Medicament> medicaments = medicamentRepository.findByUser(user);
```

or use EAGER fetch and use this code:

```
User user = userRepository.findByName(name);
List<Medicament> medicaments = user.getMedicaments();
```

or maybe I can change this if I need (in one way I use entity with fetch EAGER and in other way I use this same entity with fetch LAZY)?

Edit:

I found solution:
I have changed query to:

```
@Query("select u from User u JOIN FETCH u.medicaments m where u.name = :name")
User findByNameQuery(@Param("name") String name);
```

And entity User have fetch LAZY, in controller i use:

```
User user = userService.findByName(name);
List<Medicament> medicaments = user.getMedicaments();
```

Comment: You don't even have to use `JOIN` in the query since you have got the relationship specified using the annotation. Hibernate does all the work. Simple `@Query("select u from User u WHERE u.name = :name")` should do it